# Prolog frequently used rules and facts

Tags: prolog, predicate, ontology

Is there any standard predicate library for Prolog? I am working on a chat bot which will have common sense. Besides mathematical rules and facts I also need some English basic predicates, for example

```
even(A) :- 0 is A mod 2.
odd(A) :- 1 is A mod 2.
...

man(X) :- person(X), male(X).
woman(X) :- person(X), female(X).
father(X,Y) :- parent(X,Y), male(X).
...
```

It would be hell of a job to put all those basic rules and facts by hand. I know there are thousands of people doing similar predicates but is there any collection? If there are separate collection of rules and facts in field of relation, math, general knowledge etc.

Comment: are you looking for an ontology (and don't know the word)?  if so, well, the word's "ontology"...

Comment: i agree with andrew, search about ontologies, they are basically collections of facts/rules about various fields. on the other hand, usually they are more complex than prolog

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, I am really sorry for not knowing the proper term! I hate to present excuses, but thats because I just never had someone who can tell me this.

Comment: that's ok!  glad i could help...

Comment: Of interest: [Cyc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyc) - Attempting to assemble a comprehensive ontology and knowledge base.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could also add:

```
even(X) :- got_revenge(X).
even(X) :- got_same_ammount_as_others(X).
man(X) :- man_kind(X).
```

So these basic rules are not simple.
You can use something like wordnet: http://wordnet.princeton.edu/

Older version come as a Prolog packege http://wordnetcode.princeton.edu/2.1/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, your answer is something i am looking for. But there is not enough documentation on the usage. I am in windows7 so i cant install the wordnet 2.1 as described there. I dont need a software to interpret the logics. I just need the prolog predicates. I already have the program ready which will use this predicates.

Comment: The files included are actually Prolog databases. The documentation is difficult but there are tutorials/examples elsewhere online that some Googling should find.